# Is there a better builder pattern in scala companion object apply than Companion.forBla.withBla.withBla?

Tags: scala, builder

What If I have multiple ways to create an object, should I be using multiple **apply** methods in my companion object? it would make it ugly to have multiple apply methods I prefer a single one.  But if I have multiple ways to construct my object that would mean I'm back to the standard **builder** pattern as i used in java. (**Companion.forBla.withBla.withBla**)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to differentiate between a [*builder*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) and a [*factory method*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

A *builder* is used to **avoid a telescoping constructor** where you create multiple constructors to enable users to create the object with different attributes. Therefore using multiple `apply` methods in companion objects results in such telescoping constructors and can lead to cluttered code (anti-pattern). An example would be:

```scala
case class ComplexClass(foo: String, bar: Int)

case class ComplexClassBuilder(foo: Option[String], bar: Option[Int]){
  def withFoo(f: String) =
    this.copy(foo = Some(f))

  def withBar(b: Int) =
    this.copy(bar = Some(b))

  def finish = {
    // this is the place to decide what happens if there are missing values
    // possible ways to handle would be to throw an exception, return an option or use defaults
    ComplexClass(foo getOrElse ":D", bar getOrElse 42)
  }
}
```

A *factory method* is commonly used to **enable polymorphism**. An `apply` method is a great way of implementing a factory method

```scala
trait C

case class Foo() extends C

case class Bar() extends C

object C {
  def apply(isAwesome: Boolean): C = isAwesome match {
    case true  => Foo()
    case false => Bar()
  }
}
```

But as always, those are patterns not rules. It is common to use one or two apply methods to allow creation of objects with different parameters. But if you need to set a lot of different values, you should avoid the `apply` method and implement a builder.

Answer (score 3):

Your question sounds like a matter of opinion or taste. (Why do you think having multiple `apply` methods is ugly?).

Method parameters can have default values, and parameters can be named:

```
class MySomething(val one: String, val two: Int)

object MySomething {
  def apply(one: String = "hello", two: Int = 0) = new MySomething(one, two)
}

// Creates a MySomething with one = "hello" and two = 0
val a = MySomething()

// Creates a MySomething with one = "bye" and two = 0
val b = MySomething("bye")

// Creates a MySomething with one = "hello" and two = 2
val c = MySomething(two = 2)
```